# Get Date Object with formatted date

Tags: java, date

I have a Date() object which always gives me date in a particular format (Comes in-built with Java). I want to get store Date in a specified format ("MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"). I cam across one similar approach to do that-

```
Date date = new Date();
String dateFormat = "MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
dt1.format(date);
```

dt1.format(date) returns a formatted date in **String data type**. I want something similar which will return formatted date in **Date data type**.

Comment: Don't forget to add programming language tag, this is important.

Comment: *formatted date in Date data type*... what?

Comment: @AleksandrM Is there a way to get formatted date in Date data type?

Comment: How do you want to format date object?? Why?

Comment: May i ask you, why do you want it as Date ? Maybe we can find a workaround.

Comment: See any of the **many** questions and answers here on StackOverflow for generating a string from a date-time value. Search "java date format".

Answer (score 3):

> I want something similar which will return formatted date in Date data type.

That is not possible. `Date` objects do not have a format by themselves, you cannot have a `Date` object in a specific format. You'll have to find another way to do what you need to do.

Comment: Answer is correct. A java.util.Date represents a moment on the time line of the Universe, implemented as the number of milliseconds since the beginning of 1970 (UTC/GMT). A single Date instance may be used to generate strings in various human-readable formats for different countries & cultures for various time zones around the world. But the Date instance is never "in a format", the Date instance is used to *generate a string* that is "in a format". Same goes for a DateTime instance in the alternative [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear but I suspect what you want is parse a given String with a date into a Date object? If that is so, this should help: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/4216767#4216767).

Given your example code, it would look like this:

```
String dateString = "June, 01 2014 08:23:51";
String dateFormat = "MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateString);
```

Comment: Have you worked it out can you show example how you work on your solution.

Comment: I added some sample code.